# In sas application Set date parameter and put it in the contacted column to retrieve data in a certain period

Tags: sas

The date in the table is not one set,
Days in the days column and months in the month column and years in the year column
I have concatenated the columns and then put these concatenation in where clause and put the parameter I have made but I got no result

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Please update your question and post some sample data, the code you've tried, and a more detailed description of your problem.

Comment: Please post your sample data as text in your question, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are querying a date dimension table, and you want to extract the record that matches a certain date.

Solution:

1. I created a dates table to match with,

   `data dates;
   input key day month year ;
   datalines;
   1 19 2 2018
   2 20 2 2018
   3 21 2 2018
   4 22 2 2018
   ;;;
   run;`

Output:

[image: Dates DataSet]

2. In the where clause I parse the date '20feb2018'd using day, month & year functions: in SAS you have to quote the dates in [''d]

   `proc sql;
   select * from dates
   /*if you want to match todays' date: replace '20feb2018'd with today()*/
   where day('20feb2018'd)=day and month('20feb2018'd)=month and year('20feb2018'd)=year;
   quit;`

Output:

[image: Select Output]

Answer (score 0):

if you compare date from day month and year, then use mdy function in where clause as shown below. it is not totally clear what you are looking for.

```
  proc sql;
  select * from dates
  where mdy(month,day, year) between '19feb2018'd   and '21feb2018'd ;
```